# What exactly is Azure Cosmos DB's _ts based on?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'd like some clarity around the `_ts` field, and exactly when the value is determined, especially as it relates to committing a write.

From a practical perspective, my question boils down to this:

If I execute this SQL query against a CosmosDb container:

`SELECT VALUE GetCurrentTimestamp()`

And then use that value as a `@Timestamp` parameter to execute this query:

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE c._ts < @Timestamp`

And then execute that exact query a second time.  Is it possible to get additional results in the second query that weren't yet committed when I executed the first?

Comment: I'm going to say "yes" it is possible that you get additional results second time around. e.g. if you are running your query against a geo replicated database and there is a replication lag for the write to propagate. Or even in a non geo replicated case if you are using a consistency level that only reads from a Single Replica - whether or not it is possible under stronger consistency levels I don't know

Comment: Anecdotally... when I fire off a `CreateItemAsync` with a large document with 50,000 properties on a collection with 1,000 RU, sleep 200 ms then fire off a `SELECT MAX(c._ts) AS max_ts, GetCurrentTimestamp() as current_timestamp, count(1) AS docCount FROM c` the values from the `SELECT` are values that don't yet include the document being concurrently inserted. And the `_ts` the inserted document is assigned is later than the `currentTimestamp` from the previous statement. So `_ts` does appear to be the timestamp as at the end of the statement execution rather than when the write started.

Answer (score 1):

`GetCurrentTimestamp()` returns current time (represented in milliseconds since Jan 1 1970) at the time you call it. Every time you call it, you'll get a different value (unless you happen to get two calls to execute within the same 1ms time slice).

`_ts` is the most recent create/modify timestamp Cosmos DB applies to a document (represented in seconds since Jan 1 1970).

So yes, you can do a comparison of `_ts` and `GetCurrentTimestamp()`, except you would be comparing seconds to milliseconds (since Jan 1 1970), so you'd need to convert them to be the same resolution.

Comment: Is `_ts` a rounding or a truncation?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I'm not qualified to answer that (as I'm not on the Cosmos DB team).